# Discord.py slash command

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

I made a function that echoes a text with classic commands. I wanted to make it with the slash command, but it didn't work. Honestly, I was confused, and the discord.py documentation wasn't precise about many things.

In my code, the first two arguments are reserved for channels and time.

The bot will check if the two arguments are provided. If one or both are not, it will ignore them. This is for the channel:

```
async def echo(ctx, *args):
#If a command is not followed with a text
if not args:
    await ctx.send("Please provide some text for me to echo dummy.")
    return

#Channel mention
if args[0].startswith("<#") and args[0].endswith(">"):
    channel_id = int(args[0][2:-1])
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)

    #If the channel is not valid or doesn't exist
    if not channel:
        await ctx.send("Invalid channel mention.")
        return

    args = args[1:]
else:
    channel = ctx.channel
```

The rest of the code is for the time argument:

```
#Check if there is a time argument
time_match = re.match(r"(\d+)(h|m)", args[0])
if time_match:
    time_delta = timedelta(hours=int(time_match.group(1))) if time_match.group(2) == "h" else timedelta(minutes=int(time_match.group(1)))
    await ctx.send(f"I will echo the message in {time_delta}.")
    await asyncio.sleep(time_delta.total_seconds())

    args = args[1:]
else:
    time_delta = timedelta()

message = " ".join(args)
await channel.send(message)
```

I found that converting those will require a lot of understanding, and I am a beginner at python.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understood your problem correct, that creating slash commands is not working for you? I know 2 main ways of how to create slash commands with `discord.py`:

1. Use [discord.Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client) and manage the commandTree on your own
2. Use [discord.ext.commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) and use cogs to create commands

Also i want to point out the difference between the `commands` and the `app_commands`.

`app_commands` are the commands you know as slash commands. They are supported by the discord api and will show up in the text channel after typing "/". The normal `commands` are unknown to disocrd. Discord only sends all text messages to `discord.py`. `discord.py` works out if a command was texted or not and will call the coreesponding method.

I highly recommend using `commands.Bot` and cogs. Also this example is based on it.
So first of all your class for a bot should inherits from `commands.Bot`. Also we add the mehtod [`setup_hook`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=setup_hook#discord.ext.commands.Bot.setup_hook) to load all cogs you are going to implement.

```py
class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.all(), command_prefix='/')

    async def setup_hook(self):
        for file in os.listdir(f'./cogs'):
            if file.endswith('.py'):
                await self.load_extension(f'cogs.{file[:-3]}')
```

Now you can create you first cog in a subfolder named "cogs". I recomment to create one file for every Cog. So for this exmaple we create a file and put the following code inside(note that the name inside `@app_commands.command` defines how the command will be shown in discord):

```
class MyCog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @app_commands.command(name='test_command')
    async def test_command_method(self, ctx: discord.Interaction, param1: str = None, param2: str = None):
        if param1 is None:
            param1 = ctx.channel_id  # set default value
        if param2 is None:
            await ctx.response.send_message(f'param2 missing!')
            return
        await ctx.response.send_message(f'Called with parameters param1: "{param1}" and param2: "{param2}"')


async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(MyCog(client))
```

The last thing you need to do is to add another Cog, which will sync your created commands with the discord api, so you can see them in discord after typing "/". Note, that this is using `commands` and not `app_commands`! So the sync command will not appear after typing "/", but any other `app_command`  does (after syncing).

```
class Sync(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def sync(self, ctx: Context, spec: Optional[Literal["~", "*", "^"]] = None) -> None:
        ctx.bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=ctx.guild)
        synced = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
        await ctx.send(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands {'globally' if spec is None else 'to the current guild.'}")


async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(Sync(client))
```

If you have all this things set up correctly and your bot starts without errors you can type "/sync" in any textchannel on any discord server the bot is connected to. After this you should be able to see your commands after typing "/" in a text channel.